# how to add lit-elements in nuxt js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, polymer, nuxt.js, lit-element

*****[Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside

, or missing 
. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render. vue.runtime.esm.js:619
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:
  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
found i***
*

> at components/HelloWorld.vue
> <Pages/index.vue> at pages/index.vue
>
> <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
>  vue.runtime.esm.js:619

- 

here's the error I got**

https://github.com/rajbhojani77/lit-demo

project is here

Comment: Please provide some code as of where it does come from. Also, why does it have a polymer tag?

Comment: i just want to create components using lit element in nuxt js. i have create one component but it giving this error

Comment: Please provide some code as of where it does come from. Also, why does this question have a polymer tag attached to it?

Comment: Could you provide some other details about the code itself and the tech stack versions? Info like which versions of Nuxt, Vue, and Lit you are using would be helpful

Comment: https://github.com/rajbhojani77/lit-demo here is code @kissu

Comment: https://github.com/ais-one/lit-element-vue here is vue code. in vue this component works but in nuxt it notworking @AlanDávalos